# Function interposition: about the use of a static function variable

Tags: c, gcc, function-interposition

I want to interpose a library function from a third party, using LD_PRELOAD, and I have seen the following code pattern in a lot of places:

```
void interposed_func()
{
    static void(*real_func)() = NULL;

    if (real_func == NULL)
       real_func = (void(*)())dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "interposed_func");

    real_func();
}
```

It calls to my attention that `if` at each call of the function. What's wrong with just:

```
void interposed_func()
{
    static void(*real_func)() = (void(*)())dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "interposed_func");
    real_func();
}
```

Since `real_func` is a static function local variable it will only be initialized once right? I don't understand why all of the examples I have faced uses an additional but (in my view) unnecesary `if`. Is there any else to consider that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It depends on whether (void(*)())dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "interposed_func"); is a constant expression. Static variables must be initialized by constant expressions.

Comment: I'll say don't bother. The `if` makes your code safer, and it won't be a top-ten (probabvly not even a top-100) bottleneck in your program.

Comment: Please compile it before you post the question.

Comment: `if (real_func == NULL) real_func = (void(*)())dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "interposed_func");` creates a race condition, as does your simplified code, even if it compiled.  Multiple threads can read and/or update `real_func` simultaneously.  And the cast is not needed in C.

Answer (score 3):

Objects with static storage duration (i.e. those declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword) may only be initialized with a constant expression, as such initialization effectively happens at compile time.

Your second example does not qualify because a function call is not a constant expression.  It would be the same as trying to initialize a file scope variable with a function call.

The first example is required to satisfy the requirement of a constant initializer.  The overhead of a NULL check on each access is minimal.

Also, the conversion on this line:

```
real_func = (void(*)())dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "interposed_func");
```

Is technically not allowed by the C standard, as it converts an object pointer to a function pointer.  The proper conversion would be this:

```
*(void **)(&real_func) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "interposed_func");
```

As noted in the [man page for `dlsym`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) in an example:

> ```
>    /* Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
>        would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
>        casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
>        The assignment used below is the POSIX.1-2003 (Technical
>        Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale for the
>        POSIX specification of dlsym(). */
>
>    *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");
> ```

Comment: In both C and C++?

Comment: @ABu C++ does allow function calls for static initialization (i.e. for constructor calls), however there is no guarantee regarding the order in which these initializations occur.

Comment: Re “The overhead of a NULL check on each access is minimal”: That is a value judgement that is not applicable in all situations. An alternative is to initialize the pointer with the address of a routine that performs the `dlsym` call and updates the pointer. Then it can always be used as `real_func()` with no check (although issues of multithreading remain).

Answer (score 1):

None is correct.

1. The second code will not compile in C.
2. The code doesn't check if the symbol exists. If `dlsym` does not exist you will be calling a NULL pointer converted to a function pointer which is UB

```
void interposed_func()
{
    static void(*real_func)() = NULL;

    if (real_func == NULL)
       real_func = dlsym(0, "interposed_func");

    if(real_func) real_func();
}
```

Comment: And that's still not thread-safe as it's a race condition.